# C++ operator overloading not possible with **

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a class called Complex, why I'm allowed to define the following function:

```
Complex operator+(Complex& c1, Complex& c2);
```

But I can't write:

```
Complex operator**(Complex& c1, Complex& c2);//for power
```

Comment: There is no `**` operator in C++.  C++ lets you overload operators, not create new ones.

Comment: There are [only](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) 39 operators you can overload in c++, and `**` is not one of them. You'll have to pick one of the others.

Comment: You may consider `^` instead of `**` (although that's actually bitwise XOR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`over.oper`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper), you can see which operators can be overloaded. You will notice that `**` is not one of the valid operators to overload. There is, however, the `^` operator you can use (although it's usually meant for bitwise)

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot create new operators this way, so you cannot make a new one for `**`

Answer (score 2):

`**` is not a valid C++ operator on its own, it is simply two `*` operators with no whitespace. We cannot create new operators in C++, but `operator*` can be overloaded as an unary or a binary operator. `operator*` can be implemented as a non-member function, member function, or friend function, depending on the class structure. Below is an example of `operator*` implemented as a binary, non-member function, which returns a new `Example` object.

```cpp
struct Example {
    int x;
};

Example operator*(Example a, const Example& b){
    return a *= b;
}
```